# How to create a Dict in Elm for testing?

Tags: elm

To create a list in elm you can do:

```
list = ["test","test2"]
```

But how can I create a Dict for testing purposes?

I've read [Dict - core 3.0.0](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Dict).

Comment: I am still recommending you read the [complete docs](http://elm-lang.org/docs) first :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`let dict = Dict.fromList [("key1", "value1"), ("key2", "value2")]`

To insert an element: `let dict' = Dict.insert "key3" "value3" dict`

To look up an element:

```
case Dict.get "key1" dict of
  Just value -> ... -- do something with value
  Nothing -> ... -- no such value in dict
```

Comment: `Dict.lookup` seems to be called `Dict.get` now. http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Dict